# Day not showing up in JS Date Script

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to show the date on the webpage as "Wednesday, January 22, 2014" Instead I am getting a undefined, January 22, 2014.

What am I missing?

```
  <p>Today's date is: <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var days = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");
var months = new Array(
"January", "February", "March", "April",
"May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
"October", "November", "December");
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth();
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
document.write(days[day] + ", " + months[month] + " " + day + ", " + year);
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: see this library https://github.com/minagabriel/dtmFRM/blob/master/dtmFRM.js

Comment: DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/8fPtd/3/

Answer (score 1):

not that you've asked but what about using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: Please add these kind of answers as comments to the question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Should have tried one more thing:

```
  <p>Today's date is:  <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var days = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");
var months = new Array(
"January", "February", "March", "April",
"May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
"October", "November", "December");
var currentTime = new Date();
var today = currentTime.getDay();
var month = currentTime.getMonth();
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
document.write(days[today] + ", " + months[month] + " " + day + ", " + year);
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: `getDay()` vs. `getDate()` :-)